# connection between Google play services and the android google maps v2

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. Here is my question. I want to know the reference between Google play services and the android google maps v2. why we should install google play services in our emulator? what is the connection between these two. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the classes that relate to developing an application that includes Google Map API V2 are located inside the `google-play-service` library, so if you open it in you development environment, you will find there the: `com.google.android.gms.maps` package.
inside it there are the `GoogleMap`, `MapFragment` and `SupportMapFragment` classes and many other for developing using the Google Maps API V2

Comment: you welocme @user2781812 : )